# Get value from percentage in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to find value by a percentage on a particular value.

**For example**

**Scenario 1**

10 * 75% = 7.5

**Scenario 2**

20 * 75% = 15

So I tried this but gave an error. So anyone how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: There is no operator for percentage in any programming language. % calulates the remainder after division. If you want 10 * 75%. Write 75% as 0.75.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I'm pretty sure it exists in some programming languages, but yeah, kotlin isn't one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` symbol in Kotlin, and many other languages, isn't actually used for percentages. It's the symbol for the 'modulo' operator, and does something different from what you want.

To calculate a percentage, divide the value by 100.

For example, 75% of 10 is `10 * 0.75`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to round value in int? For example `7.5` is to **7** and `7.6` to **8**

Comment: Use Double.roundToInt()